# React Native Crash Undefined is not an object (Evaluating 'Sn[e]')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Any one facing react native build issue?
I am trying to generate debug build but its crashing when the app is launched .

The exception has no useful information.

I was facing the same issue with

```
sudo react-native run-android
```

But that got resolved after upgrading RN from 0.48 to 0.55(latest Stable Version)

But the crash remain same for the apk generated using

```
sudo gradlew assembleDebug
```

The crash is similar to 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16745

please see screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After so much struggle , finding solutions from different sources , I got to know that assembleDebug is not bundling by itself. So bundle it assets explicitly using below command

```
 react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

and then generate build

```
sudo gradlew assembleDebug
```